# Update Firestore Specific Values in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I've succeeded in reading certain values in the Firestore from the flutter.
We used Stream Builder to call you in as below

```
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('1_email', isEqualTo:currentUser.currentUser!.email).snapshots(),
```

But I don't know how to update that
It was successful to update only one value as shown below

```
Future updateUserDetails(String name, String phone, int age) async{
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc('BwmlWJR7k9PwQQkTu5jJ').update({
      '2_name' : name,
      '3_phone' : phone,
      '4_age' : age,
    });
  }
```

I tried to code it similar to reading certain data, but I couldn't solve it

```
Future updateUserDetails(String name, String phone, int age) async{
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('1_email', isEqualTo:currentUser.currentUser!.email).update({
      '2_name' : name,
      '3_phone' : phone,
      '4_age' : age,
    });
  }
```

error code :

```
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'currentUser'.
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('1_email', isEqualTo:currentUser.currentUser!.email).update({
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with,

```
Future updateUserDetails(String name, String phone, int age) async {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).update({
    '2_name': name,
    '3_phone': phone,
    '4_age': age,
  });
}
```